# Sell iBooks through iOS App

Tags: ios, ibooks

Supposed I have an app where I can sell supplementary content in the form of an iBook. They take 30% either way, but I could use the app as a platform to sell it. Is there a way I can sell this through the app itself, but keep the features of the iBook? (multi-touch, iBook author, etc)

I could distribute via MDM or something over the air, but I would prefer a streamlined method of:

Purchase > Opens in iBooks > Read

The other option would be to use a UIPageViewController to duplicate the functionality of the book in the app itself. It would seem like I was reinventing the wheel though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With iOS 6.0 or later you can use `SKStoreProductViewController` to sell other apps, books, music, etc. Pretty much anything from iTunes can be sold from within your app.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it'll get rejected if you sell stuff in the app without using In-App purchases